# Strange Having and Group By clauses behaviour generating "Unknown column in 'having' clause" error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in `MySQL` database:

**table1**

```
mysql> SELECT ID FROM table1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  6 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**table2**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table2;
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+
| id | placeId  | dictionaryId           | dictionaryCode       |
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+
| 54 |        6 |                      1 | MarketingTerritoryID |
| 53 |        6 |                      1 | PlaceTypeID          |
+----+----------+------------------------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can you please explain why the following sql query is working:

```
SELECT 
   table1.id
FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS placeType
    ON table1.id = placeType.placeId
      AND placeType.dictionaryCode = 'PlaceTypeID'
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS region
    ON table1.id = region.placeId
      AND region.dictionaryCode  = 'MarketingTerritoryID'
GROUP BY region.dictionaryId
HAVING region.dictionaryId = MIN(1)
```

... and the other one

```
SELECT 
   table1.id
FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS placeType
    ON table1.id = placeType.placeId
      AND placeType.dictionaryCode = 'PlaceTypeID'
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS region
    ON table1.id = region.placeId
      AND region.dictionaryCode  = 'MarketingTerritoryID'
GROUP BY region.dictionaryId, placeType.dictionaryId
HAVING region.dictionaryId = MIN(1)
```

**returns the sql error:** `*Unknown column 'region.dictionaryId' in 'having clause'*`

Note that the difference between these two queries is only in group clause: second query also grouped by *`placeType.dictionaryId`*

Here's code from sqlfiddle:

1. first query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46a85/7
2. second query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46a85/8

Comment: you have to use region.dictionaryId in select field

Comment: I just try to understand the way HAVING clause works. 
@BhavinSolanki
Then why the first query works?

Comment: @GordonLinoff What column do you mean? In both queries I'm grouping data by region.dictionaryId

Comment: @ColdShine . . . I think I mean in the `select`.   `table1.id` is not in the `group by` and is not an argument to an aggregation function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't understand your point. Why `table1.id` should be there? As it reads in the [official mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html): The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.

Comment: So according to the docs if I have the column listed in `group by` - I can use it in `having`. So the first query works perfect according to this rule: I have `region.dictionaryId` in `group by` clause and I'm using it in `having` clause. Fine. But the second query suddenly returns that strange error if I add another column to `group by` clause. That looks really strange. Honestly, it looks like a mysql bug or undocumented case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported the bug to mysql team. Here's the link: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82317

Currently it have verified status. Let's see what will they answer.